# Did people actually used poetic languages like Latin and Persian for basic spoken communication?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, poetry

I can't help but notice the older generation frequently scolding the younger ones of *corrupting* the language by introducing words like *lol, ASAP, brb, OMG, pj, etc.* Indeed, with the astronomical growth rate of mobile app usage, I wouldn't be surprised if these "words" earn the canonical status in Spoken English by the turn of the century.

But tracing back this behavior, does it seem too far-fetched to believe that in ancient and medieval times, people actually used to communicate in the languages that seem to emanate rhythmic music today?

Comment: The place of poetry in a culture varies a great deal In Persian society, and many others, making poems together is a form of entertainment. In other cultures, it has religious significance. And what sounds "poetic" in one language isn't necessarily so in another. So, yes, in the past people did in fact use those languages for communication, even though we may not have much more than poetry left today -- say, Vedic Sanskrit of the time of the _Rigveda_, which is all poetry. This was just the spoken language of the day. Making it poetry was extra.

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile What I mean by *poetic languages* is that the emphasis is more on maintaining the rhythm and structure of words and sentences. For instance, in British English, the emphasis is the most on correct pronunciation (*colour instead of color in spite of the redundant u*). In American English, the emphasis is on using fewer words and alphabets (presumably cause Americans are busier people in general). *WhatsApp English* has further reduced the American English to a few neat abbreviation words.

Comment: @PrahladYeri: Where do you get that idea? Pronunciation in most cases has nothing whatever to do with spelling, and indeed, British people do not pronounce _color_ differently from _colour_. Your generalisation is nonsense: both British and Americans (and, I suspect, most people in the world, whatever their language) sometimes speak and write carefully and sometimes don't.

Comment: Right. Poetry is spoken. In English poetry depends on stress units, that's correct. In other languages stress is not an issue -- note, for example, the difference between Medieval Latin poetry, which rhymes and is stress-oriented, and Classical Latin poetry, which does not rhyme and is based on vowel and syllable weights. A modern English speaker hears _In taberna quando sumus/non curamus quid sit humus/sed ad ludum properamus/cui semper insudamus_ as poetry. But not _Arma virumque cano/Troiae qui primus ab oris/Italiam, fato profugus/Laviniaque venit_.

Answer (score 1):

Written language for the longest time tended in large part to be of literary or legal types.  If you're going to take the time to write out something (or worse, carve it), after all, you might as well make it sound nice, pleasant, formal, and do it in some sort of standardized variant of the language.

That said, we *do* have renmants of how people spoke more generally outside of these formal contexts that let us know that the flowery language isn't how most people spoke.  Oftentimes I find evidence of it in my work when someone's moaning, complaining, or laughing about how some other person or group speaks <sub>(language pedantry, I'm sure, is as old as language itself)</sub>.  But those texts aren't the ones we normally are exposed to in Latin or Persian or other major literary languages of the past, so we often end up with a distorted view of how those languages worked at a quotidian level.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question title is yes and no. Speaking about Latin: When the Roman Empire was spread all over the nations facing the Mediterranean Sea, Latin was the official language of the empire, and so it spread as well, growing and developing. However by the time the Roman Empire fell, there was a separation between written and spoken latin, although this had already been true before this particular event.

Indeed, the first one (used mainly by intellectuals and for documents, ceremonies, bureaucracy, etc) stayed mostly the same, while the latter changed more rapidly. It was spoken by the common people, the peasants, and it was called Vulgar Latin (vulgar here is not intended as "indecent, tasteless", rather it comes from Lat. *vulgus*, meaning "common people"). For this separation we also need to take into account the lack of literacy in the lower classes.

When the Roman Empire fell, communications also fell apart and many zones stayed more isolated. Due to various influences (mainly by the populations present in each region) we could have witnessed the birth of various "vulgar languages", that ultimately became what we now know as Romance Languages.

In conclusion, even though Latin had a certain status throughout the ages, not everyone was able to speak or write it "properly". Certainly not everybody could speak Classical or Medieval Latin, but only a modified version of it which increasingly changed from written latin as time went on.